# Angular combine 2 output events to call 1 function

Tags: html, angular

I would like to know if it is possible in Angular 4 to have two ouput events calling 1 function?

## e.g.

```
<input type="button" value="send" (click, keydown.enter)="doMagic()"/>
```

instead of doing

```
<input type="button" value="send" (click)="doMagic()" (keydown.enter)="doMagic()"/>
```

@HostListener is not an option.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't seem so - at least not from this issue asking for it as a feature:  https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6675

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Very sad they dont want to implement this in near future. Would be essential for clean coding!

Comment: If you really need it there's this: https://medium.com/@TheLarkInn/hacking-angular2-binding-multiple-dom-events-f781b14ef676 but it does mean implementing it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution - may be worth considering.

template:

```
<input #send type="button" value="send" />
```

component:

```
@ViewChild('send') sendElement: ElementRef;
sub: Subscription;
ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.sub = Observable.fromEvent('click', this.sendElement)
        .merge(Observable.fromEvent('keydown.enter', this.sendElement))
        .map(t=> this.doMagic()).subscribe();
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.sub.unsubscribe();
}

doMagic() {
  ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. it is a good alternative but unfortunately too much code :-(

Comment: @dspies add your new code as a new answer rather than editing an existing answer.